# how to keep content observer running even when OS has low memory

Tags: android, service, contentobserver

Pleas let me explain the scenario fist.

I have been writing a Dropbox like android app, which automatically upload photos to the server. When user turn on upload service, it keeps running at the background as long as it can.

The Service is used to upload photos, but I also added a Content Observer to watch camera event, because I need to upload the newly taken photo instantly. The Content Observer will detect camera event and upload the new photo. Until now everything is alright.

As I passed START_STICKY to the Service to make it keep running and restore itself after OS has enough memory. But the Content Observer does not. And that made the problem.

I need to ensure Content Observer functions as long as the service does, because the user may take camera photo at any time. The Content Observer has to detect the camera event at the background and upload it.

I glistered the Content Observer in onCreate() method under Service class, and unregisterd it under onDestory() method. see the code

> ```
> @Override
> public void onCreate() {
>             Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onCreate");
>             // bind transfer service
>             Intent bIntent = new Intent(this, TransferService.class);
>             bindService(bIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
>             Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "try bind TransferService");
>             this.getApplicationContext()
>                     .getContentResolver()
>                     .registerContentObserver(
>                             MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, false,
>                             cameraUploadObserver);                        
>         }
>         @Override
>         public void onDestroy() {
>             Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onDestroy");
>             cancelUploadTasks();
>             /*this.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver()
>             .unregisterContentObserver(cameraUploadObserver);
>             cameraUploadObserver = null;*/
>             if (mTransferService != null) {
>                 unbindService(mConnection);
>                 mTransferService = null;
>             }                
>         }
>         @Override
>         public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
>             Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onStartCommand");
>             Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onStartCommand.intent: " + intent);
>             initializeCameraUploadPreference();
>             if (repoId != null && accountEmail != null) {
>                 isCameraUpload = true;
>                 account = new Account(accountServer, accountEmail, null, accountToken);
>                 cUploadManager = new CameraUploadManager(account);
>             }    
>             if (isCameraUpload) {
>                 Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onStartCommand.startPhotoUploadTask");
>                 ConcurrentAsyncTask.execute(new PhotoUploadTask());
>             }            
>             return START_STICKY;
>         }
> ```

Below is how cameraUploadObserver was created and used

> ```
> private CameraObserver cameraUploadObserver = new CameraObserver();
>     private class CameraObserver extends ContentObserver {
>           public CameraObserver() {
>               super(null);
>           }
>           @Override
>           public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
>               super.onChange(selfChange);
>               Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "CameraOberser onChange");
>               ConcurrentAsyncTask.execute(new CameraEventReceiverTask());
>           }
>       }
> ```

So anyone can tell me why the service can keep running but the Content Observer, is there any code I need to add to keep the Content Observer running? any comments, advice, reference from you will be appreciated.

Comment: Where and how is cameraUploadObserver created? Also I see in your code unregistering observer is commented out.

Comment: @Okas I updated the question and posted more code.

Comment: @Okas I unregistered Observer to test if it keeps running as long as Service

Comment: Could you please give more info. How exactly do you detect that service is running and observer does not receive notifications?

Comment: @Okas I added logs to service and observer respectively, at the beginning both printing logs. The service logs were printed even when I left the app into background and opened a lot other ram-consuming apps. Noticed that the service logs were interrupted several times when OS under really low memory then it continued. But for Observer, once the log stopped, it never restore back.

Comment: you can go github to view my complete source https://github.com/Logan676/seadroid/blob/lg2/src/com/seafile/seadroid2/sync/CameraUploadService.java

Comment: Im really out of ideas. Have you tried providing handler to observer constructor, instead of null?